# How to decode Raw Protocol Buffers Data exported from AppEngine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, protocol-buffers, decode

I've dumped my entire Database using appcfg.py from AppEngine. The result is an SQLITE3 database with a 'result' table. This table contains three fields, a key, a data and an index fields. The data field is containing the Entity data, with the fields, but it's all encoded in Protocol Buffers format. I'd like to extract this raw protocol buffers format into an array or something what is easy to parse (preferably in PHP).

I have the original Entity model structure in Python. I've examined several Protocol Buffers library but I haven't found a method yet so far to extract RAW Protocol Buffer data.

Is there any simple method to do that in PHP? I don't want to generate and encode protocol buffers; I want to decode raw protocol buffer data using the easiest/simplest possible way.

Comment: Have you considered using bulkloader https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata#Configuring_the_Bulk_Loader and download the data as csv or xml.  It will probably save yourself a lot of time.

Comment: Thank you Tim - yes I've considered it (still considering). Unfortunately I have all my data exported from AppEngine already and it literally took days because of the extreme large amount of data. If there is a chance to raw decode my local dump that would be awesome. Otherwise I might have to re-export using model transformations or create an app and run it which will export in a proper format. Thank you for your tip tho, I might have to do it if I can't decode it locally.

Comment: it might be worth digging into the bowels of upload_data process which reads the blobs from the sqlite3 result db and see if there is anything of use there.

Comment: Good idea - meanwhile, I've started a BulkLoader export, just in case. =)

Comment: dev_appserver has an option to use a sqlite3 database, is it possible to load your results there?

Comment: i have tried loading 1.5million items into the dev server - not very successfully ;-)

Comment: I've ended up using the bulloader. I've analyized the protocol buffer specification and implementations and I've decided I won't implement it or make further research for a one time project. bulkloader was really helpful tho (i had to do a lot of massive edits afterwards to restructure the data into a standard rdbms, but that's another story). thanks again for everyone for the support and ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The encoded protocol buffer is an instance of the `Entity` protocol buffer, found in the Python SDK as [google.appengine.ext.datastore.entity_pb](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/datastore/entity_pb.py). There are undoubtedly PHP Protocol Buffer libraries, but you'll first need to find a copy of the Entity Protocol Buffer definition, and use the library to construct a reader for it. It's likely to be much simpler to use the existing support in the Python SDK, and write a simple Python script to extract the relevant fields from the Protocol Buffers and output them in a format that you can easily load in PHP.

To decode a Protocol Buffer in the Python API, you do this:

```
entity = entity_pb.EntityProto(contents=data)
```

Comment: After I carefully examined all the available options, and all the available PHP libraries I found your solution is the easiest to extract data from encoded PB format. However, as Tim commented above, the best solution is probably to use the bulk downloader so extraction can be avoided at all. Thank you for your answer.